# GDI+ methods are missing

Tags: winapi, gdi+

So I'm trying to use the method [Bitmap::GetHistogram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-gethistogram) from GDI+ but apparently it doesn't exist. I already made sure to initialize everything with

```
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

at the start of WinMain, here's the problematic snippet:

```
    UINT numEntries;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap myBitmap(pszFilePath);
    Gdiplus::Image myImage(pszFilePath);

    UINT iHeight = myImage.GetHeight(); // works
    UINT iWidth = myImage.GetWidth(); // works
    myBitmap.GetHistogramSize(HistogramFormatRGB, &numEntries); // not defined
```

These are all the header files included:

```
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
```

The method simply isn't' there:

[image]

What might causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Add `#define GDIPVER 0x110` before the #includes.  The program won't run on ancient Windows versions, Vista or higher required.  Not much of  a problem today.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I'm curious as to why this happened

Comment: Hard to answer without insider access to the troubled Longhorn project. I suspect that there were plans to back-port the improvements to XP/2003.  Didn't happen, the Vista release was fairly buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious as to why this happened

Because the method needs the GDIPVER >= 0x0110 in gdiplusbitmap.h:

```
#if (GDIPVER >= 0x0110)
...
inline Status
Bitmap::GetHistogram(
    IN HistogramFormat format,
    IN UINT NumberOfEntries,
    _Out_writes_bytes_(sizeof(UINT)*256) UINT *channel0,
    _Out_writes_bytes_(sizeof(UINT)*256) UINT *channel1,
    _Out_writes_bytes_(sizeof(UINT)*256) UINT *channel2,
    _Out_writes_bytes_(sizeof(UINT)*256) UINT *channel3
)
{
    return DllExports::GdipBitmapGetHistogram(
        static_cast<GpBitmap *>(nativeImage),
        format,
        NumberOfEntries,
        channel0,
        channel1,
        channel2,
        channel3
        );
}

inline Status 
Bitmap::GetHistogramSize(
    IN HistogramFormat format,
    OUT UINT *NumberOfEntries
)
{
    return DllExports::GdipBitmapGetHistogramSize(
        format,
        NumberOfEntries
        );
}

#endif // (GDIPVER >= 0x0110)
```

All recent OS (>= Vista) have GDIPlus 1.1. But if you do not specify `GDIPVER` to 0x0110 to enable the function of version 1.1, the default version will be specified as 1.0 in gdiplus.h:

```
// Define the Current GDIPlus Version
#ifndef GDIPVER
#define GDIPVER 0x0100
#endif
```